# Unable to Parse response headers

Tags: php, python

I'm writing a script that sends a GET request, then assigns the value of the `Location` header in the response to a variable, This is my script so far.

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.example.com/";

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'max_redirects' => '0',
        'ignore_errors' => '1'
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$stream = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);

$headers = stream_get_meta_data($stream);


?>
```

this script saves the resp headers to an array , now when trying to call any object in the above array i get an error, for example

```
echo $headers[3];
```

i get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxx/file.php on line 24
```

here's what i want to do but in python:

```
import requests


url = "https://test.com/file.php?next=google"
headers = {"Cookie":"asd=123"}

req = requests.get(url,headers=headers,allow_redirects=False)

print "<img src=\""+req.headers['Location']+"\" >"
```

Comment: Do `var_dump($headers);` to see what the variable actually contains.

Answer (score 0):

solved by using

```
echo echo $headers["wrapper_data"][0];
```

instead of

```
echo $headers[0];
```

Comment: `$headers["wrapper_data"][0];` does not return `location` data